# Посчитайте число нулевых столбцов в матрице

Tags: python, numpy

Единственное, что не получается - определить вводиться ли одна строка или один столбец, потому что метод shape дает только одно значение в кортеже

```
import numpy as np
import sys
matrix = np.loadtxt(sys.stdin)
s = 0
a = np.array(matrix)
for i in range(0,a.shape[1]):
    matrix = np.array(a[:,i],int)
    if np.all(matrix == 0):
        s += 1
print(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

Зачем так сложно? Во-первых в `matrix` у вас уже `ndarray`. Во-вторых действуйте *векторно*, иначе зачем вам вообще `Numpy`? Цикл не нужен:

```py
import numpy as np
import sys

matrix = np.loadtxt(sys.stdin)
print((matrix==0).all(axis=0).sum())
```

Comment: Премного вам благодарен, я только начал изучать numPy, поэтому так подтупливаю))